# Starting vim with vimfiles in a certain location

Tags: vim, windows-7

One of vim's more often used configurations is having a folder structure like this

```
\[vimfiles]
\[vim73]
\_vimrc
```

How can I start vim with _vimrc and [vimfiles] being in some other folder? The folder in question in not one of those which vim upon starting checks automatically?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903936/howto-change-location-of-vimrc-and-vim/16907192#16907192

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a custom location for the `~/.vimrc` file; `:help startup` has all the details. For example, you could pass a file location via `-u`, or define a `:source file` command in the environment variable `VIMINIT`.

Once you're running your own vimrc file, the loading of plugins is determined by the `'runtimepath'` option. Therefore, if you want to use a non-default location (not `~/.vim` / `~/vimfiles`), just `:set runtimepath=...` to it.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it: https://github.com/mihaifm/vimfiles

Let's say you have Vim installed in `E:\Vim` and you want to load your vimfiles from `D:\Dropbox\vimfiles`

Edit your `E:\Vim\_vimrc` like this:

```
set rtp+=D:\Dropbox\vimfiles
source D:\Dropbox\vimfiles\_vimrc
```

Alternatively you can create symbolic links with the `mklink` and `junction` tools.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose the new path will be `C:\Config\Username\Vim`;
2. Create a **user** environment variable `VIMINIT` and set it to `source C:\Config\Username\Vim\_viminit`;
3. Create `C:\Config\Username\Vim\_viminit` and add `source C:/Config/Username/_vimrc` to it;
4. Create that `_vimrc` and add `set runtimepath+=C:/Config/Username/Vim/vimfiles` to it;
5. (optional) Create `C:\Config\Username\Vim\_gvimrc` for GUI specific settings and add the following at the end of `_vimrc` in order to load it at startup:

   ```
   if has("gui_running")
     source C:/Config/Username/Vim/_gvimrc
   endif
   ```
6. (optional) Add `set viminfo+=nC:/Config/Username/Vim/_viminfo` to `_vimrc` in order to also store the viminfo file in the custom location.