# Change location of vimrc

Tags: linux, vim

I'm trying to unclutter $HOME, and want to move my .vimrc into ~/.vim.  I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109667/change-default-location-of-vimrc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903936/howto-change-location-of-vimrc-and-vim), but none of the solutions presented are what I'm looking for.

I do not want to alias vim with the -u flag because it won't be appropriately set if it is opened in some other way than from the shell.

I do not want to use a symbolic link because it still shows up in $HOME.

I will not compile it from source, I'd rather just use a symlink (which is what I'm currently doing) than deal with that mess.

Can anyone offer some new ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change default location of vimrc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109667/change-default-location-of-vimrc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using 7.4, you can simply move your `~/.vimrc` file into your `~/.vim/` directory:

```
~/.vim/vimrc    <--- "vimrc", not ".vimrc"
```

Try [this method](http://tlvince.com/vim-respect-xdg) if you don't use 7.4.

Comment: You could also upgrade your Vim to 7.4.

Comment: Ended up adding the following to my .bash_profile: `export VIMINIT='source $MYVIMRC'`
    `export MYVIMRC='~/.vim/vimrc'`